# How to change the size of the EditText hint in TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

I'm trying to change the hint size in `TextInputLayout`, but it's not working as desired. This is what I'd like to achieve:

[image: Desired result]

---

`styles.xml`

```
<style name="TextLabel" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Hint">
    <item name="android:textSize">44sp</item>
</style>
```

`fragment.xml`

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextLabel"
    android:hint="Password">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24sp"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

This code works only for the floating label, when the `EditText` isn't empty, but I want to change the hint size in the `EditText` itself, when it is empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The size of the regular hint text is set to the `EditText`'s text size when that is added to the `TextInputLayout` during inflation/initialization. This value is ultimately set on a private helper class in `TextInputLayout`, and there is no publicly exposed method or field to change it.

However, we can do a little juggling with the text sizes by subclassing `TextInputLayout` to intercept the adding of the `EditText`. When the `EditText` is added, we cache its text size, set the desired hint size as its text size, allow the super class to add it and initialize the hint, and finally set the `EditText`'s text size back to its original value.

For example:

```
public class CustomTextInputLayout extends TextInputLayout {

    private float mainHintTextSize;
    private float editTextSize;

    public CustomTextInputLayout(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public CustomTextInputLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public CustomTextInputLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs, R.styleable.CustomTextInputLayout);

        mainHintTextSize = a.getDimensionPixelSize(
            R.styleable.CustomTextInputLayout_mainHintTextSize, 0);

        a.recycle();
    }

    @Override
    public void addView(View child, int index, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
        final boolean b = child instanceof EditText && mainHintTextSize > 0;

        if (b) {
            final EditText e = (EditText) child;
            editTextSize = e.getTextSize();
            e.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, mainHintTextSize);
        }

        super.addView(child, index, params);

        if (b) {
            getEditText().setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, editTextSize);
        }
    }

    // Units are pixels.

    public float getMainHintTextSize() {
        return mainHintTextSize;
    }

    // This optional method allows for dynamic instantiation of this class and
    // its EditText, but it cannot be used after the EditText has been added.
    // Units are scaled pixels.

    public void setMainHintTextSize(float size) {
        if (getEditText() != null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Hint text size must be set before EditText is added");
        }

        mainHintTextSize = TypedValue.applyDimension(
            TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, size, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
}
```

To use the custom `mainHintTextSize` attribute, we'll need the following in our `<resources>`, which we can do by just sticking the following file in the `res/values/` folder, or adding to the one that's already there.

`attrs.xml`

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="CustomTextInputLayout" >
        <attr name="mainHintTextSize" format="dimension" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

If you don't care to use the custom attribute, you can skip this file, and remove the `TypedArray` processing in the third constructor above.

This custom class is a drop-in replacement for `TextInputLayout`, and can be used just as it would. For example:

```
<com.mycompany.myapp.CustomTextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Password"
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextLabel"
    app:mainHintTextSize="12sp">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:text="qwerty123" />

</com.mycompany.myapp.CustomTextInputLayout>
```

---

[image: screenshot]

---

This approach is nice, in that it uses only publicly-accessible, documented methods, but the hint text size must be set before the `EditText` is added, whether that happens during inflation, or through direct instantiation.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a hint to have the same size for both expanded and collapsed state. You can write your own custom TextInputLayout

```
package android.support.design.widget

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.EditText

class ConstantHintSizeTextInputLayout : TextInputLayout {
    constructor(context: Context?) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)
    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)

    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    override fun addView(child: View?, index: Int, params: ViewGroup.LayoutParams?) {
        super.addView(child, index, params)
        if (child is EditText) {
            collapsingTextHelper.expandedTextSize = collapsingTextHelper.collapsedTextSize
        }
    }
}
```

**Important:** Package name should be exactly equal to `android.support.design.widget` because this solution uses accessing a package-private field, but no reflection involved, so it's fast