# TextInputEditText & TextInputLayout resize hint without affecting the floating label size

Tags: android, android-design-library, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

I have this **TextInputLayout** with **TextInputEditText** .
[my image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMQKd.png)

As you can see in the image my hint in "Pokemon Name" is too big to be in my TextInputEditText.

I want to change the Pokemon Name hint text size(for example making it smaller), but so it only affects the hint without also the floating label on focus. for example, using my XML and style I get the exact opposite of what I want:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_pokemon_a"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextLabel">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/pokemon_name"
        android:hint="@string/pokemon_name_hint"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text" />
```

and my code in styles.xml for **TextLabel** :

```
  <style name="TextLabel" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Hint">
        <item name="android:textSize">8sp</item>
    </style>
```

[This gives me this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Vazx.png)

I also tried editing my strings.xml like this:

```
<string name="pokemon_name_hint"><font size = "15">Pokemon Name(e.g. Pikachu)</font></string>
```

any suggestion? thank you in advance!

Comment: If you don't mind using a custom subclass of `TextInputLayout`, I've a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40184765.

Comment: Mike this was helpful for me. please add it as a solution so I can vote it.

Comment: Ah, good to hear. In these cases, however, we prefer to mark questions as duplicates, pointing to a single one, so we don't have redundant information spread across multiple posts, which might eventually go out of sync. Thank you, though. I appreciate the offer. Glad I could help. Cheers!